# How to implement Pagination buttons which allow you to jump to any page using Ag grid in React.js?

Tags: pagination, datagrid, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to implement pagination and pagination buttons at the bottom allow you to jump to any page including special buttons for first page, previous page, next page and last page.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import React from 'react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

function Read(props) {
  const \[record, setRecord\] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
    .then((response) =>{
      console.log(response.data);
      setRecord(response.data);
    })
  }, \[\])

  function update(data){
    console.log("hello");
  }

const col= \[
    { headerName: "Name", field: "name"},
    { headerName: "Email", field: "email"},
    { headerName: "Body", field: "body"},
    {headerName: "", headerClass: 'new-class',
        cellRendererFramework:(params)=>
        <div>
                  <button onClick={() => update(params.data)}>Edit</button>
        </div>}
  \]

  return (
    <>
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height:'400px',
        width: '700px'}}>
        <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={col}
            rowData={record}
            pagination={true}
            >
        </AgGridReact>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Read;
```

[image]
this is how i want to display the page numbers

Answer (score -1):

There is an example on the ag-grid website that allows the user to jump to page 5 or 50:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-pagination/#example-custom-controls

With a bit of editing you could use this example?

Comment: it will not work these are direct link to page numbers even if you mention all the number but when you click on particular page it will not hide starting and ending page numbers